# Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable magento2

Tags: magento2

Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable: productViewEvent in /vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Plugin/ReportsProductCollectionPlugin.php on line 60
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ9oS.png)

Comment: Please provide a description: at least of your situation, what you are trying to achieve, when this error occurs, and what you have tried to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

That issue already exists in repository dotmailer
https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/issues/570